# Trying to fit a gaussian with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a diffractogram, and I need to fit a given peak to a gaussian function, I'm trying to use `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize` for that but I'm getting some errors. First at all, because of my data, I've added a straight line to the equation to fit, so I have

[image]

When I try to fit this equation via

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def gauss(x, mu, sigma, m, b):
    return (1.0/(sigma*np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)))*np.exp((-(x-mu)**2)/(2.0*sigma**2)) + m*x + b

#load the dataset
datadrx = np.genfromtxt('data.txt')

X = datadrx[:,0]
Y = datadrx[:,1]

mu0 = np.mean(Y)
sigma0 = np.std(Y)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss, X, Y, p0 = [mu0,sigma0, 1.0, 1.0])
plt.title('Gaussian fit')
plt.plot(X, gauss(X,*popt))
plt.plot(X,Y)
```

I get this warning

```
/home/eariasp/miniconda3/envs/herrcomp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:906: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',
```

And a straight line as a fit, see

[image]

When I remove the `mx+b` part I get a 'better' fit (I mean better because at least it's not just a straight line), but it's still far away from what I want

[image]

So, my question is, what is wrong? I found that it's a good idea to define the guess parameters `p0` so I did it, but it didn't work in my case

In order to reproduce, you can use [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F5V1bVWm01lRuWfaiA5yq8R7MUREOCmt/view?usp=sharing) dataset

Check that values in the first column are one close to another, I don't know if that has something to do, like subtractive cancellation, taking e to a negative small power or something; I found something about that but really I didn't get it

Comment: Two things: 1) Mind adding code showing how to load the data.txt file in the correct format? 2) The formula as written cannot possibly fit your function: it contains no term that lets the area of the Gaussian vary. The area under the curve of the Gaussian can only ever be 1. But the area under the curve of the function you're trying to fit is clearly much bigger.

Comment: @NickODell, @Reinderien I've edited the question, now there is a line for loading the `data.txt` file, and since the file contains just the data restricted to `start` and  `end`,  there's no need to provide those. Just execute what's above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need initial parameters; no, you're not calculating them correctly. The mean of Y is **not** the mean of your random variable, and the standard deviation of Y is **not** the standard deviation of your random variable.

The better your constraints and guesses are, the faster and more reliably your fit will converge. Thankfully, for a Gaussian such constraints and guesses are reasonably straightforward to calculate - and in fact the guess is *so* good that for some (not all) applications, fit isn't even needed.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def gauss(x: np.ndarray, a: float, mu: float, sigma: float, b: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return (
        a/sigma/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
    )*np.exp(
        -0.5 * ((x-mu)/sigma)**2
    ) + b


X, Y = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=' ').T
xmin, xmax = X.min(), X.max()  # left and right bounds
i_max = Y.argmax()             # index of highest value - for guess, assumed to be Gaussian peak
ymax = Y[i_max]     # height of guessed peak
mu0 = X[i_max]      # centre x position of guessed peak
b0 = Y[:20].mean()  # height of baseline guess

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Properties
# Index of first argument to be at least halfway up the estimated bell
i_half = np.argmax(Y >= (ymax + b0)/2)
# Guess sigma from the coordinates at i_half. This will work even if the point isn't at exactly
# half, and even if this point is a distant outlier the fit should still converge.
sigma0 = (mu0 - X[i_half]) / np.sqrt(
    2*np.log(
        (ymax - b0)/(Y[i_half] - b0)
    )
)

a0 = (ymax - b0) * sigma0 * np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
p0 = a0, mu0, sigma0, b0

popt, _ = curve_fit(
    f=gauss, xdata=X, ydata=Y, p0=p0,
    bounds=(
        (     1, xmin,           0,    0),
        (np.inf, xmax, xmax - xmin, ymax),
    ),
)
print('Guess:', np.array(p0))
print('Fit:  ', popt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Gaussian fit')
ax.scatter(X, Y, marker='+', label='experiment', color='orange')
ax.plot(X, gauss(X, *p0), label='guess', color='lightgrey')
ax.plot(X, gauss(X, *popt), label='fit')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
Guess: [2.43599321e+02 6.86947536e+01 2.23407054e-01 3.02000000e+02]
Fit:   [2.28882618e+02 6.86885140e+01 2.25575284e-01 3.02398123e+02]
```

[image: fit and guess]

Your data are also too noisy and don't have enough samples for `m` to have any meaning.

Comment: I was completely wrong. Thank you!!
About the slope I just need them `m` and `b` later to define the height of the peak with respect to that line, it's supposed to be that noisy

Comment: `b` is certainly required to "define the height of the peak with respect to that line", but `m` is not